# Error while trying to load a component inside a angular material modal - Angular 10

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm trying to load a component inside an Angular material modal
and receiving the next error from the compiler:

```
ERROR in ... error NG8001: 'app-component-to-load' is not a known element:
    1. If 'app-component-to-load' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
    2. If 'app-component-to-load' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
```

but both components are declared in the same Module

The example is very simple:

**modal HTML (angular material modal)**

```html
<div>
  <app-component-to-load></app-component-to-load>
<div/>
```

Comment: maybe stop and restart your app?

Comment: add this component in ```entry components`` array in module

Comment: @SantoshShinde tried that, did'nt work

Comment: It's hard to know what is wrong without seeing the code for the actual component and the module. Could you please add those? Thanks!

Comment: @Anna please create stackblitz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `app-component-to-load` and dialog component in entry components array in module and it will work.

Here is working demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-gplwpt